# if else on sql using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do if else statement on sql? I want to execute this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM mouvements,
     articles,
     clients,
     fournisseurs
WHERE mouvements.id_art = articles.id_art
  AND IF(mouvements.type_mouv = "true",
         mouvements.id_fournisseur = fournisseurs.id ,
         mouvements.id_client = clients.id_cli)
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this without much complexity by using purely logical operators:

```
SELECT *
FROM mouvements,
     articles,
     clients,
     fournisseurs
WHERE mouvements.id_art = articles.id_art
AND (
  (mouvements.type_mouv = "true" AND mouvements.id_fournisseur = fournisseurs.id)
  OR (mouvements.type_mouv <> "true" AND mouvements.id_client = clients.id_cli)
)
```

However, it is generally best practice to use explicit `JOIN`s like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mouvements m
LEFT JOIN articles a ON (m.id_art = a.id_art)
LEFT JOIN clients c ON (m.type_mouv <> "true" AND m.id_client = c.id_clie)
LEFT JOIN fournisseurs f ON (m.type_mouv = "true" AND m.id_fournisseur = f.id)
```

Note that you can also use an `INNER JOIN` over a `LEFT JOIN` to exclude results where the conditions of the join are not fulfilled.

A further note on best practice: If you are selecting all columns (`SELECT *`) while joining tables, you'll quickly find yourself with a *lot* of data, it's better for maintenance and performance to limit your `SELECT` to only the columns you need, with explicit table identifiers, e.g. `SELECT m.id_art, m.id_fournisseur`.

Comment: This answer is correct but remember to consider NULL values (should enter on the "false" side).